# React - recoger datos de url?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, reactstrap, programación-reactiva

Tengo definida una ruta en < App > de esta forma

```
import ViewDiet from "./components/diets/view.component";


      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route path="/diets" component={ViewDiet} />
      </Switch>
```

El código del componente ViewDiet tiene este código

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class viewDiet extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items : [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://api-diets.local/api/diets/99999')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {

                this.setState({

                    isLoaded:true,
                    items: json,
                })

            });

    }

    render() {

        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {

            var divStyle = {
                color: 'red',
            };

            return (

                <div style={divStyle}>

                    <p>Id : {items.id} </p>
                    <p>Name : {items.name} </p>
                    <p>Description : {items.description} </p>    
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

EL código funciona correctamente, lo que no consigo es donde hace el "fetch" para obtener los datos y es una ruta con un ID en la URL, no consigo recoger allí el parámetro.

La linia en questión es esta

```
fetch('http://api-diets.local/api/diets/99999')
```

Comment: Por lo que veo en el constructor inicias `items` como un arreglo, sin embargo en el render no lo iteras, sino que accedes directamente a `items.id`, `items.name`, etc... como si fuera un objeto. ¿que es lo que verdaderamente te retorna `api/diets/99999`, un arreglo o un objeto? ¿muestra algún error por consola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda muy clara tu pregunta, no puede obtener un parametro desde el navegador?
Si quieres obtener un id desde la url, tienes que especificar que esperas un parametro en el Route, asi:

```
<Route path="/diets:id" component={ViewDiet} />  // tuhostname.com/diets/9999
```

Y ya en tu componente ViewDiet puedes acceder a ese parametro de esta manera con la ayuda de destructuring:

```
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
  console.log(params.id) // mostraria 9999
```

Como comenta @alter-lagos si tu endpoint regresa un arreglo de objectos la manera en que estas mostrando la informacion no es la correcta, tendrias que iterar cada item de tu arreglo con la ayuda de `.map`

```
render() {

        const {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        const divStyle = {
            color: 'red',
        };

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }


            return (

                <div style={divStyle}>
                   {items.map(item => (
                     <p>Id : {item.id} </p>
                     <p>Name : {item.name} </p>
                     <p>Description : {item.description} </p> 
                   ))}
                </div>
            );
    }
```

Tambien como buena practica, es mejor ya no usar `var` y mejor usar `let` o `const`. Tambien el `else` esta demas ya que si entrar al primer `if` renderea el loader y no el listado de items.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, el concepto lo entendí. Solo tengo una duda esta linia "const { match: { params } } = this.props;" va dentro del constructor?

Comment: @ilernet puede ir en donde necesites tus parametros, ya sea en el constructor o dentro del metodo `render` o en algun otro metodo.